# Http.post() is changing the payload from an object to a function

Tags: http, spring-boot, post, angular6

i'm developing a proyect with angular 6 as front end and spring boot as REST back end. (English is not my native language so, i apologize in advance for the grammar.)

All was nice until i've got an error in some method.

I was making a http.post request from my front end service and getting an error from spring boot saying content-type application/text wasn't allowed (this is not happening for other PostMapping methods, but whatever) i managed to change post headers with this code:

```
persistGame(game: Game) {
    const path = 'http://localhost:8080/games';
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    const options = new RequestOptions();
    options.headers = headers;
    console.log(game);
    return this.http.post(path, Game, options);
}
```

then, the console.log shows the correct object but my back-end started to complain `""timestamp":"2018-09-05T20:11:04.848+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'function': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'function': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 10]","path":"/games"}"`

When i checked the payload i found this

```
"function Game() {
    }"
```

instead of my object....

my back-end method looks like this:

```
@CrossOrigin()
@PostMapping(path = "/games")
public ResponseEntity<Object> createGame(@RequestBody Game game) {
    ResponseEntity<Object> output;
    String body;
    Game gameInBD;
    gameInBD = gameService.findByName(game);
    if (gameInBD == null) 
    {
        gameService.saveGame(game);
    } else 
    {
        /* updates gameInDB fields with game fields and persist gameInDB */
    }
    output= ResponseEntity.ok(game);

    return output;
```

how can i avoid this conversion from object to function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the class as parameter to the post

It should be like this
‘return this.http.post(path, game, options);’

With lowercase game

Comment: It happens to all of us ;)